# Math to identify number of results in a page

Tags: delphi, math

For whatever reason, I can not figure out how to identify the number of results in a given page. I have a list of data, and a property `PageSize` which identifies how many results should fit in one page. Let's say there's 120 results and the page size is 25. That means there should be a total of 5 pages, the first 4 having 25 records, and the 5th having just 20 records. Right now, the results I'm getting are all over the board, for example I might get `50` when it's supposed to be `20`.

I'm writing this function to return the number of results in a specified page, but I can't seem to get the simple math right (I was never very good at math). There are no actual lists per page where I can simply read `Count` to identify the number of records in that page - I need to dynamically calculate it, using this function.

Refer to the line of code just under `CALCULATION DONE HERE`:

```
function TMyData.SizeOfPage(const Index: Integer): Integer;
begin
  //Index = Page Number (0 ... MAX)
  //Result = Number of results in given page
  //PageCount = Total number of pages (from other function)
  //RecordCount = Total number of records (all pages)
  Result:= 0; //Default
  //Validate index bounds
  if (Index >= 0) and (Index < PageCount) then begin
    if Index < PageCount-1 then begin
      //Just return full size of one page
      Result:= PageSize;
    end else begin
      //Return number of records in the last page
      //--- CALCULATION DONE HERE ---
      Result:= RecordCount - Trunc(RecordCount / PageSize);
    end;
  end else begin
    raise Exception.Create('Page index out of bounds ('+IntToStr(Index)+')');
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you have Result:= 0? You always overwrite that value, or raise.

Comment: It's a habit of always initializing a result, doesn't hurt anything.

Comment: I disagree. It's another line of code to understand. In code review I would always remove that line. The compiler warnings will tell you if you have not initialised the function result.

Comment: I would see your point in a language such as C# where it would immediately return the value, but in Delphi, the function reaches the very end before it returns. I don't rely on compiler messages to tell me when I should or shouldn't initialize results, I just always do it by default, as a standard precaution. However I know your point of it being an irrelevant line of code in the example above, but it should be necessary to include all code related to the issue in a question, because for all we know the issue may lay in this initialization (although it's not in this case)

Comment: You are right to include all the code. This is an aside. Let's try something different. Would you be happy ever to return the value 0?

Comment: Also the code makes it clear that you are not compiling with hints and warnings enabled. Otherwise you'd see "value assigned to XXX is not used" messages. That's a bad move. This functionality regularly finds mistakes in my code, as I am coding.

Comment: I think there's more unnecessary comments here now than there is unnecessary code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see no reason to use floating point arithmetic here. I always avoid floating point arithmetic if integer arithmetic suffices.

I would write it like this:

```
ItemsOnLastPage := 1 + (RecordCount-1) mod PageSize;
```

Or perhaps this version:

```
ItemsOnLastPage := RecordCount - (PageCount-1)*PageSize;
```

This is particularly easy to understand. You subtract the records shown on all the full pages, and what is left are the records on the last page.

As far as `PageCount` goes, you can calculate it like so:

```
PageCount := (RecordCount+PageSize-1) div PageSize;
```

Thanks to @Rob for his insight.

Comment: To remove the special case, calculate `PageCount` like this: `PageCount := (RecordCount + PageSize - 1) div PageSize`.

Comment: I would have replied much sooner if our internet hadn't dropped out, I'm a big fan of making things easier, and this is one of them, thanks!

Comment: That actually is exactly how I identify `PageCount` in a separate function, that part is working fine, but thanks.

Comment: Good. I wanted to be sure that you were not doing any floating point!